# What exactly is EPIC architecture?

Tags: architecture

EPIC- Explicitly Parallel Instruction Computing

How is it going to make RISC and CISC obsolete?

Came across [this paper](http://www.scribd.com/doc/1902877/risc-cisc)

Answer (score 1):

I'll be honest - I have no idea what this is about - so I went looking.  The short answer is that I'm not sure you'll get much trattic here on SO about this.

Natrually I turned to Wikipedia; amongst other things I found that...

> HP later asserted that "EPIC" was
>   merely an old term for the Itanium
>   architecture.

Reading about [Itanium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itanium) on Wikipedia makes it sound like Itanuims going away - not forward, and the articles I've seen to mix Itanium and EPIC as though they are the same thing - which they aren't - it's just that Itanuim seems to be the first (only?) EPIC based system.

In addition to [CISC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_instruction_set_computing) there's also "[Zero instruction set computer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZISC)" (ZISC), and others - but it took me a while to find a reference to EPIC in the CISC / RISC based content.  I wasn't able to open the article you found :(